# Открыть файл .txt при помощи скрипта Python с неизвестным именем, но известным расширением

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начал изучать Python, пытаюсь написать скрипт, который будет открывать только-что созданный файл (.тхт).  Проблема в том, что имя файла всегда уникальное. Файлы в папке создаются другой программой, результат выполненной работы, в данной папке файлы хранятся постоянно, нужно открывать именно последний созданный файл. Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, проверяйте через `os.listdir()` список файлов и сравнивайте с предыдущей проверкой чтобы получить список новых файлов.

Comment: может быть поможет это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python

Answer (score 2):

***NB** Это только одно из возможных решений.*

[os.scandir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) возвращает файлы и директории по указанному пути. Они фильтруются по расширению. Из всех выбирается файл c самым большим временем изменения (самый последний):

```
import os
import sys


def get_files(path, ext):
    for e in os.scandir(path=path):
        if e.is_file() and e.name.endswith('.' + ext):
            yield e


def get_last_file(path, ext):
    return max(
        get_files(path, ext),
        key=lambda e: e.stat().st_mtime,
        default=None
    )


def main():
    path = sys.argv[1]
    ext = sys.argv[2]
    lf = get_last_file(path, ext)
    if lf is None:
        print('N/A')
    else:
        print(lf.name)


main()
```

> ```
> $ python latest-file.py . txt
> temp1.txt
>
> $ python latest-file.py . py
> latest-file.py
> ```

**P.S.** Ещё есть [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob), [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir).